# Dojo DGrid RQL Search

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am working with a dgrid where I want to find a search term in my grid on two columns.

For instance, I want to see if the scientific name and commonName columns contain the string "Aca" (I want my search to be case insensitive)

My Grid definition:

```
var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, Pagination ]);
var gridStore = new Memory({ idProperty: 'tsn', data: null });
gridStore.queryEngine = rql.query;

grid = new CustomGrid({
store: gridStore,
            columns:
                    [
                    { field: "tsn", label: "TSN #"},
                    { field: "scientificName", label: "Scientific Name"},
                    { field: "commonName", label: "Common Name",},
                    ],
            autoHeight: 'true',
            firstLastArrows: 'true',
            pageSizeOptions: [50, 100],
        }, id);
```

With the built in query language (I think simple query language), I was able to find the term in one column or the other, but I couldn't do a complex search that would return results for both columns.

```
grid.set("query", { scientificName : new RegExp(speciesKeyword, "i") });
grid.refresh()
```

I started reading and I think RQL can solve this problem, however, I am struggling with the syntax.

I have been looking at these pages:

http://rql-engine.eu01.aws.af.cm/

https://github.com/kriszyp/rql

And I am able to understand basic queries, however the "contains" syntax eludes me.

For instance if I had this simple data set and wanted to find the entries with scientific and common names that contain the string "Aca" I would think my contains query would look like this:

```
contains(scientificName,string:aca)
```

However, this results in no matches.

```
[
    {
            "tsn": 1,
            "scientificName": "Acalypha ostryifolia",
            "commonName": "Rough-pod Copperleaf",
    },
    {
            "tsn": 2,
            "scientificName": "Aegalius acadicus",
            "commonName": "Northern Saw-whet Owl",
    },
    {
            "tsn": 3,
            "scientificName": "Portulaca pilosa",
            "commonName": "2012-02-01",
    },
    {
            "tsn": 4,
            "scientificName": "Accipiter striatus",
            "commonName": "Kiss-me-quick",
    },
    {
            "tsn": 5,
            "scientificName": "Acorus americanus",
            "commonName": "American Sweetflag",
    }
]
```

Can someone guide me in how to formulate the correct syntax?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm briefly reading, it appears that:

- `contains` was [replaced by `any` and `all`](https://github.com/kriszyp/rql/commit/ba5f2008d02c012d53f6cc8c7cfc180c0dcddc3a)
- these are meant for array comparisons, not string comparisons

I'm not sure offhand whether RegExps can just be handed to other operations e.g. `eq`.

With `dojo/store/Memory`, you can also pass a query *function* which will allow you to do whatever you want, so if you wanted to compare for a match in one field *or* the other you could do something like this:

```
grid.set('query', function (item) {
    var scientificRx = new RegExp(speciesKeyword, 'i');
    var commonRx = new RegExp(...);
    return scientificRx.test(item.scientificName) || commonRx.test(item.commonName);
});
```

Of course, if you want to filter only items that match *both*, you can do that with simple object syntax:

```
grid.set('query', {
    scientificName: scientificRx,
    commonName: commonRx
});
```